# How do I set the colnames of a matrix to the colnames of another matrix?

Tags: r, matrix, multiple-columns

I have one data matrix named `as.mat` with dimensions `[1] 79 1929` and another matrix, `dd.mat` with dimensions `[1] 79 1924`. `dd.mat` Has 1924 columns, but columns 1-1921 have no names.
For example, this is what it looks like when I do `colnames(dd.mat)`:

`[1] ""   ""   ""   ""   ""   ""   ""   ""   ""   ""   ""   ""   ""   ""   ""   ""   ""   ""   ""   ""   ""   ""   ""   ""   ""   ""   "" [28] ""   ""   ""   ""   ""   ""   ""   ""   ""   ""   ""   ""   ""   ""   ""   ""   ""   ""   ""   ""   ""   ""   ""   ""   ""   ""   ""`

...up to the 1921th column. But columns 1922, 1923, and 1924 have the column name "nv":

`[1918] ""   ""   ""   ""   "nv" "nv" "nv"`

How would I set the colnames of `as.mat` to the first 1921 column names of matrix `dd.mat` without renaming the 1922nd to 1924th column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do the assignment combined with indexing

```
colnames(as.mat)[1:1921] <- colnames(dd.mat)[1:1921]
```